# why can't I see jars in WEB-INF/lib(in Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse

I want to remove some jars from lib in eclipse.I can see jars in Web App Libraries and file path in computer"WebApp\WEB-INF\lib",but I can't see them in WEB-INF/lib in eclipse.I already uncheck all options in Java Element Filters.I don't know why?

Comment: Just to exclude that: Did you refresh that folder in eclipse?

Comment: I'm sure I refresh that folder many times